# Библиотека для псевдографики

Tags: c, c++

Не подскажите кросс-платформенную библиотеку для отображения контролов в консоли? Основные элементы:

1. Кнопки, радио кнопки, надписи и т.д.
2. Меню
3. Диалоговые окна
4. Простую анимацию

Answer (score 3):

[Ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html)?